# How does the Maven shade plugin decide which dependencies to put into the final jar when using the minimizeJar function?

Tags: maven, junit, maven-shade-plugin

I have a Maven project with one java file and that uses the Maven shade plugin to create an uber jar. My goal is to create an executable jar as small as possible. I decided to use the [minimizeJar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#minimizeJar) parameter in the plugin to make my jar smaller. Is the parameter only putting in the dependencies needed to run or the ones to compile or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is further up the page that you link to:

> **shade:shade**
>
> Full name: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade
>
> Description: Mojo that performs shading delegating to the Shader component.
>
> Attributes:
>
> - Requires a Maven project to be executed.
> - **Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: runtime.**
> - The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds.
> - Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: package.

So the artifacts included will be runtime (and therefore compile time as well).

EDIT: For a full explanation of scopes, please see [Introduction to the dependency mechanism - Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

In maven, when you do dependency resolution, it uses the notion of scopes - the three most important are (from that page):

- **compile** - This is the default scope, used if none is specified.
  Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project.
  Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
- **runtime** - This scope indicates that the dependency is not required
  for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test
  classpaths, but not the compile classpath.
- **test** - This scope
  indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the
  application, and is only available for the test compilation and
  execution phases.

So when you compile the sources under *src/main/java*, you will use dependencies with *compile* scope. When you run your application, you will use the dependencies with *compile* or *runtime* scope. When you compile your tests (under *src/test/java*), you will use *compile* and *test* scopes. When you run your tests with surefire, you will use the dependencies with the *compile*, *test* and *runtime* scopes.

This means that minimizeJar will contain the dependencies which are *compile* and *runtime* scope.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what it means when it says "Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: runtime."